# How to open .vol files (from 3D ultrasound) in python?

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, type-conversion, medical-imaging

I work with so called cartesian `.vol` files that come from **GE Voluson S6** ultrasound.

I'm able to open them in `Slicer 3D` application and display a 3-dimensional model as expected.

I'm aiming to convert these files to `.stl` in order to be able to use deep learning techniques to modify their content.

While this is possible with Slicer, in order to automate the process, I need to somehow convert these `.vol` files to `.stl`, preferably using `python`.

Please share any knowledge regarding this issue.

Here's a link to my google drive, containing an example of such file:
[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JN3yqTyejtMcNE0k9gvmbYI8mvKiQ-5J/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you tried to read it using [SimpleITK](https://simpleitk.org) or [NiBabel](https://nipy.org/nibabel) libraries?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I did. Both fail. SimpleSTK throws an error "sitk::ERROR: Unable to determine ImageIO reader for "my_file.vol"", and NiBabel does something similar: "nibabel.filebasedimages.ImageFileError: Cannot work out file type of "my_file.vol"".

Comment: I'm not able to open the image using `3D Slicer`, should I install any additional module to `3D Slicer`??

Comment: Yes, the extension "SlicerHeart" is necessary to open these types of files.

Comment: The tool to handle this kind of images is proprietary as you can see [here](https://github.com/SlicerHeart/SlicerHeart/blob/master/README.md#ge), there is an explanation about how to read it using Slicer [here](https://discourse.slicer.org/t/loading-of-ge-kretz-ultrasound-volumes-vol-file/808/110) but It doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: I know that, unfortunately, this is a proprietary kind of image. However, I'm still able to display it in 3D in Slicer (with the help of SlicerHeart extension) and even convert it to another format. That's why I'm hoping there is a way to fully automate the process. I've seen that code snippet already honestly it got me more confused.